# What is better: projectcontrib.pluginname or project-pluginname as a python project naming convention for small project?

Tags: python, pep8

I created a small project on Python. Main app use some plugins. I would like to know which naming convention for namespaces is better? PEP-0423 recommends to use "`project`" namespace for main program and "`projectcontrib.pluginname`" for plugins. But django or node.js often use "`project-pluginname`" convention. What are pro and cons for both conventions?

Comment: Well. After I follow PEP-0423 and try to collect all plugins in `projectcontrib.plugin` namespace I found that Python is not so easy and fun when it's about packages. So I changed all to `project_plugin` namespace convention and all problems just disappeared. But important part is: my main app automatically create virtualenv directory, so there is no any plugins in global namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, whats more important is consistency within your own code. Its important that your convention be constant. Or if you are coding with a group that your convention be consistent across your project.

With that said, each language will have its own Style Guides. Style Guides offer consistency across the different projects, and help the community use an agreed upon convention. Python Style Guides will be different than Node.js style guides. So I would recommend following PEP when you are using Python.